# Error in .local(x, ...) : plot function only supports binary classification

Tags: r, plot, svm, target, plural

> I would like to draw an SVM plot for three targets.
> However, as in the title, an error occurs, stating that only binary classification is possible.
> Which part of the code below should I modify?

```
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(kernlab)

a<-read.csv(file="Data78.csv", header=TRUE)

a$target<-as.factor(a$target)
scaling<-c("X9th","X6th")
a[,scaling]<-lapply(a[,scaling],scale)

set.seed(2023)
segmen<-sort(sample(nrow(a),nrow(a)*0.6))
train<-a[segmen,]
test<-a[segmen,]

linear<-ksvm(target!., data=train, kernel="polydot",kpar=list(degree=3),C=1000)
plot(linear, data=train)
```

> I wanted to draw an SVM plot for three targets. But, an error message appeared saying that only binary classification was possible. Thank you for your reply in advance.

Comment: SVM only works on two classes. If you want SVM to work on multiclass problems, you need to use error correcting output codes models (ECOC)